# How to stop repeated keyPressed() / keyReleased() events in Swing

Tags: java, linux, swing, event-handling, keyboard-events

So the problem that I am having appears to be a bug that occurs only on Linux. I'm trying to have my swing app record when a key is pressed down, then to detect when that key is released. Now that shouldn't be in issue because [KeyListener](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) is supposed to handle this for me.

The problem is that when I hold the key down I get lots of repeated keyPressed()/keyReleased() events instead of just the single keypressed(). Does anyone have a solution or workaround for knowing when a key is really released on linux?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue in JavaFX. When i press a key I get a keypressed event, then nothing for about half a second and then an endless stream of keypressed events for as a long as I hold the key. This seems to be an OS level issue as the exact same happens in any text editor or terminal window.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> So the problem that I am having
>   appears to be a bug that occurs only
>   on Linux

Yes this is a Linux problem.

On Windows when a key is held down you get multiple KeyPressed events but only a single KeyReleased event.

This question is asked often and I've never seen a good solution.

But I think the basis of a solution is to use a Timer. When the key is pressed you start a Timer. When you get another keyPressed you restart the Timer. So as long as the Timer interval is greater than the repeat rate of the key board the Timer will be continually reset when a key is held down. When keyPresses stop being generated the Timer will fire so you assume the key has been released. This implies you will have a delay in processing the keyReleased.

Comment: How do I get "the repeat rate of the key board" in Java? That's an OS user preferences setting, right?

Answer (score 2):

This question is duplicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457071/how-to-know-when-a-user-has-really-released-a-key-in-java).

[Here's a hack](http://tech.stolsvik.com/2010/05/linux-java-repeats-released-keyevents.html) implemented as an AWTEventListener that can be installed at the start of the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a pretty good workaround [here](http://brunez.net63.net/tutorials/keypressfix/keypressfix.php).

Comment: Link is dead again. Wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20151114111041/http://brunez.net63.net/tutorials/keypressfix/keypressfix.php

Answer (score 0):

Here's the bug from Sun (includes sample work-arounds): https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4153069

Answer (score 0):

Use the KeyEventDispatcher implementation, with it you'll make key binds correctly.