# key event keeps on Firing when key is pressed in java

Tags: java, events, key

I have menu accelerator for Exit as alt+f4  in java swings  ,When I press alt+f4 once event is fired once ,but when i keep pressing alt+f4  event keep on firing . How to stop that?

Answer (score 0):

Short of removing your key event listener, you can't stop events being received.

Instead, your business logic needs to ignore events that it doesn't want to handle. So perhaps after receiving the first event, set a boolean flag somewhere to tell your listener to ignore subsequent events.

Comment: as its multi threaded environment   so some other threads can change the value ,so is there any other way as we are using generic event

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the key listener for a period of time using a timer. Then re-attach the listener. 
Also see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736828/how-to-stop-repeated-keypressed-keyreleased-events-in-swing).