# How do i test to see if the enter key is pressed in a textfield in java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener, jtextfield

I am making a command line program and i need to test to see if the enter key is pressed.

Answer (score 9):

If the enter key is pressed in a [`JTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) while that `JTextField` has `ActionListener`s, an `ActionEvent` is fired.

```
JTextField field = ...
field.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Enter key pressed");
    }
});
```

Comment: Where is it checking that it is the Enter key that was pressed? What about if other actions took place within the textfield?

Comment: @ziggy One of the default entries in the [`InputMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getInputMap()) detects when a `pressed Enter` event passes through the [`processKeyBinding`](http://tinyurl.com/ay3kqzt) method. It then invokes an `Action` which fires an `ActionEvent`.

Answer (score 7):

Add a key listener to the text field and check KeyEvent's keyCode in keyPressed(). Try the example below:

```
public class TestEnterKeyPressInJTextField
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
    textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
    {
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
      {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
        {
          System.out.println("ENTER key pressed");
        }
      }
    });

    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer is more accurate than the first one as it detects either really enter was pressed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

command line program or gui application?

look here for [detailed answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457071/how-to-know-when-a-user-has-really-released-a-key-in-java)

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("KeyPressed: "+e.getKeyCode()+", ts="+e.getWhen());
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("KeyReleased: "+e.getKeyCode()+", ts="+e.getWhen());
}
```

press every key you want and see the KeyCode