# do something once the key is held and repeat when its released and repressed

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings, keystroke

I need to check when the user presses on a key and releases it.
If a key is held in, I will do something once.

I used the keystroke to get the button I want to relate an action with.
I used also a semaphore to overcome this problem but it looks crazy

My code:
`

```
InputMap inputMap = jPanel1.getInputMap();
KeyStroke keyPressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, 0, false);
KeyStroke keyReleased = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, 0, true);
//------------------------------------------
jPanel1.getActionMap().put("_1000Press", _1000Press);
inputMap.put(keyPressed, "_1000Press");
jPanel1.getActionMap().put("_1000Release", _1000Release);
inputMap.put(keyReleased, "_1000Release");
public Action _1000Press = new AbstractAction() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(!one){
            // do some thing
            one = true;
            System.out.println(one);
        }
    }
};
public Action _1000Release = new AbstractAction() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        one = false;
        System.out.println(one);
    }
};
```

`

When I press "1" key and hold it, it prints:
    false
    true
    false
    true
    false
    true

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `KeyEvent.VK_1, 0, false` v.s. `KeyEvent.VK_1, 0, true`, isn't it

Comment: i tried that but it's not working don't know why :S

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me

```
InputMap im = getInputMap();
ActionMap am = getActionMap();

im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, 0, false), "Press");
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, 0, true), "Release");

am.put("Press", new AbstractAction() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (!pressed) {

            pressed = true;
            System.out.println("press");

        }

    }

});

am.put("Release", new AbstractAction() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (pressed) {

            pressed = false;
            System.out.println("release");

        }

    }

});
```

Just to make sure I did this

```
am.put("Release", new AbstractAction() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        pressed = false;
        System.out.println("release");

    }

});
```

And it still worked

Printed `press` when I pressed and held 1 and then printed `release` when I released the key.  That was the only output I got

**UPDATED with Full Code**

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private boolean pressed;

    public TestPane() {

        InputMap im = getInputMap();
        ActionMap am = getActionMap();

        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, 0, false), "Press");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, 0, true), "Release");

        am.put("Press", new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if (!pressed) {

                    pressed = true;
                    System.out.println("press");

                }

            }

        });

        am.put("Release", new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if (pressed) {

                    pressed = false;
                    System.out.println("release");

                }

            }

        });

    }

}
```

Comment: what platform do you use ?
i use ubuntu 12.04 and netbeans and your code doesn't work with me

Comment: Ahh, I'm using Windows :P (with Netbeans) - I'll have a look and see if my Mac does the same thing

Comment: @MahmoudHosny Tried both examples under MacOS X Lion without issue. Sorry, looks like an issue with Ubuntu. I was testing with JDK1.6.0_24 under Windows and JDK1.6.0_33 under Mac. I even tried JDK1.7.0 under Windows and they all work fine

Comment: Absolutely, thought I might need to make it `focusable`, but it worked just fine - I added the full code just in case

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can achieve what you need in Linux, because the operating system continually issues press/release signals to the JVM.

See

- [How to stop repeated keyPressed() / keyReleased() events in Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736828/how-to-stop-repeated-keypressed-keyreleased-events-in-swing)
- [How to know when a user has really released a key in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457071/how-to-know-when-a-user-has-really-released-a-key-in-java)