# How do I check if the user is pressing a key?

Tags: java, input, key

In java I have a program that needs to check continuously if a user is pressing a key.
So In psuedocode, somthing like

```
if (isPressing("w")) {
   // do somthing
}
```

Comment: In java, but using a particular GUI framework (swing?)?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In java you don't check if a key is pressed, instead you *listen* to `KeyEvent`s. 
The right way to achieve your goal is to register a `KeyEventDispatcher`, and implement it to maintain the state of the desired key:

```
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class IsKeyPressed {
    private static volatile boolean wPressed = false;
    public static boolean isWPressed() {
        synchronized (IsKeyPressed.class) {
            return wPressed;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {

            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent ke) {
                synchronized (IsKeyPressed.class) {
                    switch (ke.getID()) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED:
                        if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                            wPressed = true;
                        }
                        break;

                    case KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED:
                        if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                            wPressed = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then you can always use:

```
if (IsKeyPressed.isWPressed()) {
    // do your thing.
}
```

You can, of course, use same method to implement `isPressing("<some key>")` with a map of keys and their state wrapped inside `IsKeyPressed`.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my code without checking it. See my updated answer - it uses the class object instead of the instance. Try it again (just replace both `IsKeyPressed.this` with `IsKeyPressed.class`). The `synchronized` block, by the way, isn't truly necessary in that case.

Comment: Im testing this, and it doesn't seem to be working :{. I have a timer loop that tests to see if (IsKeyPressed.isWPressed()) but it never returns true even when i press or hold the w key.

Comment: @Saucymeatman, did you get the problem solved? If you are busy waiting for `isWPressed()`, you might have caching issues. It is possible that a `volatile boolean` can solve this.

Comment: 100% perfect. Hint: If you want to test for a lot of keys, this solution can easily be expanded to use a `HashMap<Integer, Boolean>`. Integer for the `KeyCode`, Boolean for obvious reasons.

Comment: @mindoverflow I would use a Set<Integer> instead, so when a key is pressed you add it to the set and when they key is released you remove it. The Set<> would be much smaller than a HashMap, because it has to have the capacity of the maximum number of keys that can be pressed at the same time (suppose it's 10-20) instead of all the keys that can be pressed in a keyboard (dozens).

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

    JTextField textField = new JTextField();

    textField.addKeyListener(new Keychecker());

    JFrame jframe = new JFrame();

    jframe.add(textField);

    jframe.setSize(400, 350);

    jframe.setVisible(true);

}

class Keychecker extends KeyAdapter {

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {

        char ch = event.getKeyChar();

        System.out.println(event.getKeyChar());

    }

}
```

Comment: You forgot a '}'.

Answer (score 2):

## Universal method

I've built a convenience utility class based on @Elist's approach, which works with any key.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Keyboard {

    private static final Map<Integer, Boolean> pressedKeys = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(event -> {
            synchronized (Keyboard.class) {
                if (event.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED) pressedKeys.put(event.getKeyCode(), true);
                else if (event.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED) pressedKeys.put(event.getKeyCode(), false);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public static boolean isKeyPressed(int keyCode) { // Any key code from the KeyEvent class
        return pressedKeys.getOrDefault(keyCode, false);
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
do {
    if (Keyboard.isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_W)) System.out.println("W is pressed!");
} while (!Keyboard.isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `KeyListener`,take a look here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html

More details on how to use it:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html