# How can I let a program type a sentence or word in another program, with a hotkey?

Tags: java, background

I've made a program in Java that randomizes a sentence from a couple of arrays. At the moment I can generate the sentence with a mouse click on a button, but I would like it to run in the background and when you push a hotkey it will type the sentence where ever you have focus.

For example; you are chatting with a friend on Facebook and when you have focus on the textfield, where you can write, you press (for example) F12 and it generates a sentence and types it out and then you just have to hit enter.

or

When you are playing an online game and want to generate a sentence in the chat.

I've been programming on and off for the past few years, but I've never really gone very deep on any programming language.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to execute your java program.

Answer (score 0):

The `Robot` class in Java is capable of sending keyboard commands to whatever has focus. For example, the following code would probably type the character `A`.

```
Robot rob = new Robot();
rob.keyPress( KeyEvent.VK_A );
rob.keyRelease(  KeyEvent.VK_A );
```

To check if a key is pressed, you have to subscribe to the key with a listener. This is sufficiently more complicated than creating our friend rob, the Robot, so I'll simply [link to an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18037609/3224483) that has already covered this in depth.

Now that I have answered your question, I will recommend that you use [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) for your Facebook bot. Inexperienced programmers have been writing fairly sophisticated bots with AutoIt for over a decade. Here is what your key listener would look like in AutoIt:

```
While Not _IsPressed("7B") ; wait for F12 key
    Sleep(100)
WEnd
```

Heck, that script is almost human readable!