# How to check if a key has been pressed numerous times

Tags: java, input, keyboard, game-engine

For a game I am writing in java I need to open a dialogue when pressing the x key on my keyboard and then close it again when I press the x key again. The problem is whenever I press the x key its shows the dialogue on the screen for a millisecond then makes it disappear again. I think this is because it seems to think the key is being pressed multiple times instead of just once. Is there any way to make sure that I actually have to release the key before I can do the action bound to that same key again?

This is what I use to check for key presses:

```
public class KeyManager implements KeyListener {

    private boolean[] keys;
    public boolean up, down, left, right, enter, x, c;

    public KeyManager() {
        keys = new boolean[256];
    }

    public void tick() {
        up = keys[KeyEvent.VK_W];
        down = keys[KeyEvent.VK_S];
        left = keys[KeyEvent.VK_A];
        right = keys[KeyEvent.VK_D];
        enter = keys[KeyEvent.VK_ENTER];
        x = keys[KeyEvent.VK_X];
        c = keys[KeyEvent.VK_C];
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
        // System.out.println("Pressed");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: in `keyPressed()` why don't you just put `if (!keys[e.getKeyCode()])` before performing the action and setting that boolean? ie. Only do the action if the key isn't currently being pressed

Answer (score 0):

Java Doesn't "check" if a key is pressed, it listens to key events.

Here is a documentation on [how to write a key listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

if this is a swing application, [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html#eg) is much better to use.

I think this is a duplicate question and [your Question already has an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037576/how-do-i-check-if-the-user-is-pressing-a-key)