# How do I let a user interrupt an endless loop in Java?

Tags: java, loops

I've been trying several approaches to write a small program that allows a user to run one of three functions depending on the button they click. The code for the main program looks as follows:

```
public class WaspmoteSim extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
public WaspmoteSim() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.insets = new Insets(30,30,30,30);
    c.ipadx = 10;
    c.ipady = 30;
    setSize(700, 150);
    setLocation(100, 100);

    JButton button1 = new JButton("Demonstration Mode");
    button1.addActionListener(this);
    add(button1, c);

    JButton button2 = new JButton("Distribution Fitting Mode");
    button2.addActionListener(this);
    add(button2, c);

    JButton button3 = new JButton("Operational Mode");
    button3.addActionListener(this);
    add(button3, c);

    setVisible(true);
    setFocusable(true);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String command = e.getActionCommand();

    if (command.equals("Demonstration Mode")) {
        try {
            DemoMethod();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WaspmoteSim.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    if (command.equals("Distribution Fitting Mode")) {
        try {
            FittingMethod();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WaspmoteSim.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    if (command.equals("Operational Mode")) {
        try {
            OperationsMethod();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WaspmoteSim.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WaspmoteSim.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    //else {ProcessHolder.getInstance().getProcesses().get(YOUR_PROCESS_NAME).destroy();}
}
```

and the function that the third button needs to call (the one which I would like to be able to interrupt) looks as follows:

```
public void OperationsMethod() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Process proc;
        while(!IsKeyPressed.isEPressed()) {
            String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            System.out.println(workingDir);
            proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C C:\\Progra~1\\R\\R-3.2.1.\\bin\\Rscript.exe " + workingDir + "\\Fitter.r");
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
        }
    }
```

The code for IsKeyPressed comes directly from [How do I check if the user is pressing a key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037576/how-do-i-check-if-the-user-is-pressing-a-key).

However, when running the third function and pressing/holding the E key, the program simply continues looping. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting infinite output as well, or is the entire program simply hanging?

Comment: `Process#destroy` "might" work, BUT, you'd have to be running off the EDT to be safe

Comment: Infinite output; the program responds fine, but it refuses to actually close the loop.

Comment: You are linking to the article that you are refering to, but don´t show what your class `IsKeyPressed` is actually doing, or where your keylistener is applied at.

Answer (score 1):

You are starting an endless loop inside the Swing event dispatching thread. This means your `actionPerformed` method never ends. This means Swing is blocked and cannot handle any new button clicks or any other type of event.

Use a [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to fire up your `OperationsMethod()`. And use a shared and synchronized variable to share the button state between your Swing class and the SwingWorker.