# What does the following code snippet do?

Tags: java

excuse me for asking such a generic question, but I can't phrase it better.
I have seen code of this style fairly often, but have not yet used it.

```
variable= someClass.someMethod(new someOtherClass(){
      methodDeclaration(){
      }
});
```

If you don't know what I mean, the top answer could serve as an example:
[How do I check if the user is pressing a key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037576/how-do-i-check-if-the-user-is-pressing-a-key)

When is this used? Are there any examples of problems that can only be solved by such code?

Comment: This article should clarify things: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html . Anyways theres definitely a duplicate somewhere around here, I'm just too lazy to search

Comment: This is an example of an anonymous class. Your answer should be in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java).

Comment: This code snippet is using an inline anonymous class.  Just have a look at the Oracle trails for a good explanation.