# How do I run this code when holding "space" (Java)

Tags: java

I made this program that spams space bar every 17 milliseconds and I am wanting it to only spam spacebar when I am holding space. Is there Any way I can do this? I tried watching some tutorials on it but could not figure it out. I am quite new to Java but I really just wanted to make this.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class skript {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean loop = true;
        while(loop = true) {
            try {
                Robot robot = new Robot();
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);           

                try { Thread.sleep(17); } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
            } 
            catch (AWTException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(loop = true)` isn't a comparison, by the way

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037576/how-do-i-check-if-the-user-is-pressing-a-key
you need to replace `while(loop=true)` with `while(IsKeyPressed.isSpacePressed())`

Comment: Ok thanks I will try!

Comment: sorry, I am wrong about "replacing", you would need outer `while` that runs forever, but make it just `while(true)`.

Comment: Sorry I am confused on what you mean I currently have  _while(loop = true) {
  
 
 try {_

 @sschrass