# KeyBinding multiple keys pressed not working

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

So I have a painted rectangle that I want to move with the arrow keys that includes diagonal movement, or rather allowance of multiple keys being pressed at the same time (In other words, movement that is similar to player movement in a 2D game). I have attempted to do this with a KeyListener, which was not working. So I decided to move to KeyBindings and I found an example from this website: https://coderanch.com/t/606742/java/key-bindings (Rob Camick's post)

I directly copied the code and it works as intended, except it is moving an icon and not a painted rectangle like I want to do. I have attempted to modify the code so that it would move a painted rectangle, but was only failing. Here is my latest attempt, which is also a minimal reproducible:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
 
public class Test extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    public JPanel component = this;
    public int x = 100;
    public int y = 100;
    private Timer timer;
    private int keysPressed;
    private InputMap inputMap;
 
    public void addAction(String name, int keyDeltaX, int keyDeltaY, int keyCode)
    {
        new NavigationAction(name, keyDeltaX, keyDeltaY, keyCode);
    }
 
    //  Move the component to its new location
 
    private void handleKeyEvent(boolean pressed, int deltaX, int deltaY)
    {
        keysPressed += pressed ? 1 : -1;

        x += deltaX;
        y += deltaY;
 
        //  Start the Timer when the first key is pressed
        
        if (keysPressed == 1)
            timer.start();
 
        //  Stop the Timer when all keys have been released
 
        if (keysPressed == 0)
            timer.stop();
    }
 
    //  Invoked when the Timer fires
 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        repaint();
    }
 
    class NavigationAction extends AbstractAction implements ActionListener
    {
        private int keyDeltaX;
        private int keyDeltaY;
 
        private KeyStroke pressedKeyStroke;
        private boolean listeningForKeyPressed;
 
        public NavigationAction(String name, int keyDeltaX, int keyDeltaY, int keyCode)
        {
            super(name);
 
            this.keyDeltaX = keyDeltaX;
            this.keyDeltaY = keyDeltaY;
            
            pressedKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, false);
            KeyStroke releasedKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, true);
 
            inputMap.put(pressedKeyStroke, getValue(Action.NAME));
            inputMap.put(releasedKeyStroke, getValue(Action.NAME));
            component.getActionMap().put(getValue(Action.NAME), this);
            listeningForKeyPressed = true;
        }
 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //  While the key is held down multiple keyPress events are generated,
            //  we only care about the first event generated
            if (listeningForKeyPressed)
            {
                handleKeyEvent(true, keyDeltaX, keyDeltaY);
                inputMap.remove(pressedKeyStroke);
                listeningForKeyPressed = false;
            }
            else // listening for key released
            {
                handleKeyEvent(false, -keyDeltaX, -keyDeltaY);
                inputMap.put(pressedKeyStroke, getValue(Action.NAME));
                listeningForKeyPressed = true;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics tool) {
        super.paintComponent(tool);
        System.out.println(x + ", " + y);
        tool.drawRect(x, y, 50, 50);
    }
    
    public Test() {}
 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Test().create();
    }
    
    public void create() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        
        frame.getContentPane().add(component);
        inputMap = component.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        
        timer = new Timer(24, this);
        timer.setInitialDelay( 0 );
        
        addAction("Left", -3,  0, KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
        addAction("Right", 3,  0, KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
        addAction("Up",    0, -3, KeyEvent.VK_UP);
        addAction("Down",  0,  3, KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
        
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
 
}
```

Comment: *I found an example from this website: https://coderanch.com/t/606742/java/key-bindings* - that isn't the link I provided you with in your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67066490/keylistener-how-to-handle-multiple-keys-pressed

Comment: @camickr Yes that is not the link you provided, however, I did try and use your link and played around with it. I didn’t feel it necessary to post both links, and since the your link seemed like you wrote it, I didn’t want any troubles regarding your permission to post it, and I also did work a little bit more with the other link. Sorry for that. But I think I have my solution which someone posted below. Thanks for providing that code anyhow, it did give me insight on all of this key binding stuff.

Comment: The link I provided would have the most recent suggestion and was the approach I recommended. Why would you go searching for another link? Even if you found another link from me, why would you post that code here, since that is NOT the code I recommended? *I also did work a little bit more with the other link* - so why would you spend more time with the other link versus the link I recommended? There was a reason a provided the link I did.

Comment: @camickr So I couldn’t really make sense of the one you recommended, and I thank you for recommending that one. The reason I went to find other code was because I kinda gave up trying to modify your code. That’s when I found your other old code, and, from my stance, was more clear. So, because I understood the other code better, I was able to modify it better. And, because I modified it more, it seemed fit to post the older code rather than the one you suggested. I hope I didn’t offend you in any way, I just wanted to make things clear for everyone reading this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so one of the issues I have with the code you've presented is the fact that you're leak responsibility.  It's not the responsibility of the `NavigationAction` to register key bindings or modify the state the of UI.  It should only be responsible for generating a notification that the state has changed back to a responsible handler.

This could be achieved through the use of some kind of model, which maintains the some kind of state, which is updated by the `NavigationAction` and read by the UI or, as I've chosen to do, via a delegation callback.

Another issue is, what happens when the user releases the key?  Another issue is, how do you deal with the delay in repeated key press (ie when you hold the key down, there is a small delay between the first key event and the repeating key events)?

We can deal with these things through a simple change in mind set.  Instead of using the `NavigationAction` to determine "what" should happen, it should be used to tell our UI "when" something has happened.  In this a directional key has been pressed or released.

Instead of reacting to key stroke directly, we either "add" or "remove" the direction from a state model and allow the Swing `Timer` to update the state of the UI accordingly, this will generally be faster and smoother.

It also has the side effect of decoupling logic, as you no longer need to care about "how" the state was changed, only that it was and you can then decide how you want to react to it.

This approach is generally commonly used (in some form or another) in gaming engines.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface KeyActionHandler {

        public void keyActionPerformed(Direction direction, boolean pressed);
    }

    public enum Direction {
        LEFT, RIGHT, DOWN, UP;
    }

    class NavigationAction extends AbstractAction implements ActionListener {

        private KeyActionHandler keyActionHandler;
        private Direction direction;
        private Boolean pressed;

        public NavigationAction(Direction direction, boolean pressed, KeyActionHandler keyActionHandler) {
            this.direction = direction;
            this.pressed = pressed;
            this.keyActionHandler = keyActionHandler;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            keyActionHandler.keyActionPerformed(direction, pressed);
        }
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyActionHandler {

        private int xDelta = 0;
        private int yDelta = 0;

        public int x = 100;
        public int y = 100;
        private Timer timer;

        public TestPane() {
            timer = new Timer(24, this);

            InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, false), "Pressed-Left");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false), "Pressed-Right");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false), "Pressed-Up");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, false), "Pressed-Down");

            actionMap.put("Pressed-Left", new NavigationAction(Direction.LEFT, true, this));
            actionMap.put("Pressed-Right", new NavigationAction(Direction.RIGHT, true, this));
            actionMap.put("Pressed-Up", new NavigationAction(Direction.UP, true, this));
            actionMap.put("Pressed-Down", new NavigationAction(Direction.DOWN, true, this));

            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, true), "Released-Left");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true), "Released-Right");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, true), "Released-Up");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, true), "Released-Down");

            actionMap.put("Released-Left", new NavigationAction(Direction.LEFT, false, this));
            actionMap.put("Released-Right", new NavigationAction(Direction.RIGHT, false, this));
            actionMap.put("Released-Up", new NavigationAction(Direction.UP, false, this));
            actionMap.put("Released-Down", new NavigationAction(Direction.DOWN, false, this));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            timer.start();

        }

        @Override
        public void removeNotify() {
            super.removeNotify();
            timer.stop();
        }

        private Set<Direction> directions = new HashSet<>();

        //  Invoked when the Timer fires
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (directions.contains(Direction.LEFT)) {
                x -= 3;
            } else if (directions.contains(Direction.RIGHT)) {
                x += 3;
            }

            if (directions.contains(Direction.UP)) {
                y -= 3;
            } else if (directions.contains(Direction.DOWN)) {
                y += 3;
            }

            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawRect(x, y, 50, 50);
        }

        @Override
        public void keyActionPerformed(Direction direction, boolean pressed) {            
            if (pressed) {
                directions.add(direction);
            } else {
                directions.remove(direction);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This is just one more approach to solve the same problem ;)

> However, I am encountering a problem: it seems that removeNotify() is never called. I wanted to verify this and copied this post and pasted it into a new java file. I then added print statements in the add and remove notify methods, and only the print statement in the addNotify() method was printed. Also, if you add a print statement in the actionPerformed method, it prints repeatedly never ending

`removeNotify` is only called when the component, or a parent container, is removed.

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JButton btn = new JButton("Remove");
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    Container parent = getParent();
                    parent.remove(TestPane.this);
                    parent.revalidate();
                    parent.repaint();
                }
            });
            add(btn);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            System.out.println("Add");
        }

        @Override
        public void removeNotify() {
            super.removeNotify();
            System.out.println("Remove");
        }


    }
}
```

I verified that `removeNotify` will be called through the hierarchy when a parent container is removed.

Comment: Wow thanks for this. The reason my code is bad is because I don't know too much about this, and I copied someone else's code. However, that code that I copied worked, (You can copy from the website and run it yourself). So I thought I could try and modify it to my likings, but I guess I should just stick to what you posted. Thanks again.

Comment: @LuckyBandit74 It's not it's "bad", it's just not how I would do it and I wanted you to know why I modified it the way I did ;)

Comment: Thanks.  I'm working on a two-player tank (combat) game, and I needed the WASD keys to work independently from the arrow keys.  I was able to use your code and ideas to complete the movement and firing functions.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hey, so if you remember this question I was having trouble firing multiple keys and you helped with this post. However, I am encountering a problem: it seems that removeNotify() is never called. I wanted to verify this and copied this post and pasted it into a new java file. I then added print statements in the add and remove notify methods, and only the print statement in the addNotify() method was printed. Also, if you add a print statement in the actionPerformed method, it prints repeatedly never ending. It could really help if you could figure out the problem

Comment: `removeNotify` is only called when the component itself is removed from the parent container

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oh I see, I misunderstood. I asked because the repeated firing of the timer was not preferable for me but I can make a work around. Thanks again!

Comment: @LuckyBandit74 I only used these methods as a simple workable solution, as `addNotify` and `removeNotify` provides some guarantees about the state of the component.  You just as easily have a `start` and `stop` method, but you'd beed to consider the state of the component and take measures to ensure that you're not trying to update the component when it's not in an appropriate state ;)

Comment: Ok now I understand, I had a very different idea of how it worked. Thanks for the clarification, I'll stick to the convenient methods add and remove notify.