# How to get direct keyboard input in java

Tags: java, input

I do not want to use something like the Scanner class or the BufferedReader class,that's not my purpose. I want to know if the user pressed the UP key, the DOWN key, the LEFT key, or the RIGHT key, what should I use?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037576/how-do-i-check-if-the-user-is-pressing-a-key)

Comment: (1-) This question is not clear. What type of input are you asking about? Are you trying to get input in a GUI? Are you trying to get input from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UP DOWN LEFT and RIGHT as every character in the keyboard have a ASCII code, so you can actually check it out. Normally in Java, instead of checking if a key has been pressed you could use **KeyEvents**:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){

    int key = e.getKeyCode();   

    switch(key){
       case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: System.out.println("The right arrow key is 
       pressed");
       // Other operations
       break;
       case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: System.out.println("The left arrow key is 
       pressed");
       // Other operations
       break;
       case KeyEvent.VK_UP: System.out.println("The up arrow key is 
       pressed");
       // Other operations
       break;
       case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: System.out.println("The down arrow key is 
       pressed");
       // Other operations
       break;
    }                                             

}
```

You have more information in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)