# How to get the key from the ActionMap

Tags: java, swing, input, keystroke

I was wondering how I could get the key code from an `AbstractAction` in the action map.

```
for (int key = 37; key <= 122; key++) {
    this.key = key;

    if(!KeyEvent.getKeyText(key).contains("Unknown keyCode")) {
                
        if(KeyInputManager.getInputManager().getOrDefault(key, null) == null)
            KeyInputManager.getInputManager().put(key, true);
                
        component.getActionMap().put(KeyEvent.getKeyText(key), new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int keyCode = // TODO: GET KEY CODE HERE
                    KeyInputManager.getInputManager().replace(keyCode, true);
            }
        });
        component.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key, 0, false), KeyEvent.getKeyText(key));
    }
}
```

I am trying to store all the key's state (pressed or not) in a `HashMap` inside `KeyInputManager` which is accessed through `getInputManager`. To check if a key is pressed, we can use `KeyInputManager.getKeyDown(keyCode)`
Here is the code for `KeyInputManager`

```
public class KeyInputManager {
    private static final HashMap<Integer, Boolean> keysDown = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
    
    public static final boolean keyDown(int keyCode) {
        return keysDown.getOrDefault(keyCode, false);
    }
    
    public static HashMap<Integer, Boolean> getInputManager() {
        return keysDown;
    }
}
```

Comment: add `final int keyCode = key;` inside the loop, before creating the `AbstractAction`, then it can be used inside the anonymous class (actually the `final` is not needed since it is effectively final, but I prefer using it in this case just for documentation)

Comment: An `Action` in an action map is not necessarily triggered by a key press. Though in your case, as you are creating a new Action instance for every key code, the key code is known, you just have to capture the loop variable in another `final` variable (`this.key = key;`, however, is very suspicious and likely doesn’t do what you intend). If you want to listen to key events, use key event listeners. Or better, check [How do I check if the user is pressing a key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18037576/2711488) first.

Comment: @Holger yep and I got that fixed by making key `final`. And well I just ignored the idea of using this method and found a solution that does not answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int keyCode = (int) e.getActionCommand().charAt(0);
```

ActionEvent's action command basically contains the key, and since you are using single character keys, taking the first character should give you the key code as an integer.

Comment: Kind of funny but I'm using `KeyEvent.getKeyText(key)` while this code works for most of the keys, it wouldn't work for keys like - numpad keys, function keys, arrow keys.

Comment: Also this wouldn't return the correct key code and instead would return the ASCII value of the character. `KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar( e.getActionCommand().charAt( 0 ) )` is a slightly modified version of your code which returns the correct key code