# Java event after two keyEvents

Tags: java, game-engine, keyevent

I am programming a game and need to execute two keyEvents before fire();

For now I have done this to test:

```
if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
    fire();
}
```

What I need is:

```
if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) && (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
    fire();
}
```

The problem is, they need to be pressed in this sequence: First down, then up and so fire, but I don't know how can I do it.

Comment: Maintain a series of flags which indicate which keys are pressed.  I'd also recommend using the key bindings API over `KeyListener`, see [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Answer (score 2):

Keep track of time and key pressed for last 4 events in a FIFO, and see the history to decide

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is to implement a [KeyListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) (an example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457071/how-to-know-when-a-user-has-really-released-a-key-in-java)) in order to recognize exactly which event has occurred.
For example you could use a boolean variable (i.e. readyToFire) to store whether the

```
 `KeyEvent.VK_UP`
```

event produces or not a fire one.
For instance a possible implementation may be:

```
    //boolean readyToFire = false;

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
         if(e == KeyEvent.VK_UP && readyToFire){
              fire();
         }
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
         if(e == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
              readyToFire = true;
         }
         else if(e == KeyEvent.VK_UP && readyToFire){
              fire();
         }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
         if(e == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
              readyToFire = false;
         }
    }
```