# Short delay for KeyListener events

Tags: java, delay, keylistener

I am programming a little game. So far I have a player, who can move in a 2D printed tile world following the player. Here a small [preview](https://youtu.be/hJQIQFuSs18)).

Right now my player movement code looks like this:

**KeyListener class**

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

        if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Player){
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D) tempObject.setVelX(5);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A) tempObject.setVelX(-5);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && Var.jump == true) {
                tempObject.setVelY(-10);
                Var.jump = false;
            }
        }
    }
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

        if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Player){
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D) tempObject.setVelX(0);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A) tempObject.setVelX(0);
        }
    }
```

**Player class**

```
public void tick() {
    if (Var.falling == true) {
        velY += Var.gravity;
        if (velY > 10) {
            velY = 10;
        }
    }
    x += velX;
    y += velY;
```

These codes are just parts of the classes.

**Problem**

When I am moving to the right or to the left with A or D and then tap the other key (from a to d/ from d to a) in a certain way, my character stands still for a short time and then moves after this short delay. See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJjb27vzV0w&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "A certain way" is? Ideally, if you can work it out, the precise sequence of keydowns and keyups. It might help to log these in your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say what the exact problem is without knowing the exact sequence of keyups and keydowns, but it looks as if your program is vulnerable to overlapping keyup/keydown sequences - for example:

```
A down -> velocity = -5
D down -> velocity = +5
A up   -> velocity = 0 // but you want it to still be +5
```

Add logging to your game code to help debug these situations.

There are a number of ways to handle this, but one way is to keep a running count of currently-down keys:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
     heldKeys++;
     ... other code ...
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
     heldKeys--;
     ... other code ...
     if(heldKeys == 0) {
          velocity = 0;
     }
}
```

This is lightweight but blunt. A more refined approach might be to keep a record of the state of each key:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    heldKeys.set(key, true);
}
```

... do your game state updates on the basis of what's in `keyStates`.

Depending on how fanatical you want to get about efficiency, `keyStates` could be a `HashSet(Integer, Boolean)` or something more specialised of your own creation.

---

BUT! See [How to know when a user has really released a key in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457071/how-to-know-when-a-user-has-really-released-a-key-in-java) for discussion on auto-repeat from the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

1. User presses <kbd>D</kbd>, which triggers a call to `keyPressed`, which calls `tempObject.setVelX(5)`.
2. User releases <kbd>A</kbd>, which triggers a call to `keyReleased`, which calls `tempObject.setVelX(0)`.  This halts your character’s motion.
3. User is still holding down <kbd>D</kbd>, so after a short delay, that key’s autorepeat triggers another call to `keyPressed`, which causes `tempObject.setVelX(5)` to be called again, causing the character to start moving again.

You should not be calling `tempObject.setVelX(0)` unless *no movement key* is pressed.

How do you determine that?  You need to define instance fields which keeps track of them.  For example:

```
private boolean leftPressed;
private boolean rightPressed;

// ...

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    //...

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        rightPressed = true;
        tempObject.setVelX(5);
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        leftPressed = true;
        tempObject.setVelX(-5);
    }

    //...
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    //...

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        rightPressed = false;
        if (!leftPressed) {
            tempObject.setVelX(0);
        }
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        leftPressed = false;
        if (!rightPressed) {
            tempObject.setVelX(0);
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

Some side notes:

- `gameObject` would be a much better variable name than `tempObject`.
- You should never write “*booleanVariable* == true”.  Instead, just write *booleanVariable*.  This avoids any possibility of an accidental assignment by writing one ‘=’ instead of two.  For instance:

```
    if (Var.falling) {
```

Put more simply:  remove every occurrence of `== true` from your code.